# Gehalt, Lohn und Entlohnung

Tags: meaning, difference

What is the difference between these three seemingly similar words?

- Lohn
- Gehalt
- Entlohnung

Comment: Was sagen denn die Wörterbücher und Lexika?

Answer (score 5):

**Lohn** is connected to working by the clock.

> Stundenlohn

wage by hour

> Lohnstückkosten

unit labor cost

> Lohnunternehmer

e.g. threshing contractor (bills by the clock as long the machine/engineer works)

---

**Entlohnung** simply means *payment for work*, in contrary to *payment for some goods*. So a contractor can also be **entlohnt**.

> Die Entlohnung für die verrichteten Arbeiten erfolgte am Ende des Tages.

Payment for the work carried out was done at the end of the day.

---

**Gehalt** traditionally was a fixed salary someone gets.

> Er bekommt ein hohes Gehalt.

He gets a high salary.

> Das Gehalt wird immer am 1. auf ihr Konto überwiesen.

Your salary is being transfered to your bank account each 1st day of the month.

Today, the difference is neglible, as most people work by the clock in Germany (there's a minimum pay law which requires this.)

However, tax still makes a difference of *Lohnsteuer* and *Einkommenssteuer*, as the *Lohnsteuer* is meant to be transfered directly by your employer to the state, while you have to pay the *Einkommenssteuer* yourself e.g. when lease out a room of your house or have another source of income besides your job(s).

Ah, yeah, there's **Einkommen**. That's *income*. That simple.

Comment: I consider *Entlohnung* a formal term, to be found only in laws and working contracts, but not typically used in conversation. And there are of course further words as *Honorar*  and *Salär*.

Answer (score 5):

As an Austrian citizen I'm not sure about the situation in Germany or Switzerland. (There are lots of legal differences between those countries.) But I'm sure there soon will be some comments about this. Please read them.

I'm only talking here about the situation in Austria. Here we have this differences:

### Entlohnung

This is a generic term. It means any payment for professional work. (Everything except the money farmers get; see below.)

### Einkommen

This is the sum of all the periodically (every week, moth, year, ...) incoming money from which a person can live (i.e. from which he/she can pay what ever is needed to live). This can also be money you earn from selling land (if you have enough land to periodically sell pieces from it), or interests that you earn from your wealth. So »Einkommen« is not always payment for work. (But it is very often.)

»Einkommen« is also the money a farmer gets for selling his products. (There is a paragraph about farmers at the end of my answer.)

### Lohn

In Austria we have laws that make a strict distinction between »Arbeiter« (worker) and »Angestellte« (employees). Simplified: A worker (»Arbeiter«) is a person who has a boss and who mainly works with his or her hands: A painter, a barber, a builder, a cleaner, ...

»Lohn« is the official term for money that an *Arbeiter* gets for his or her job.

Just to make clear: A person without a boss (i.e. a freelancer) is not an »Arbeiter«, even if he/she does the work of an *Arbeiter*. No boss = no *Lohn*.

### Gehalt

An Angestellter (»employee«) is a person also having a boss but who is sitting in an office (this again is a little bit simplified). A big part of the work of an *Angestellter* is writing (on paper in former times, now by using a computer) or any kind of planing or managing. In Austria an »Angestellter« (employee) doesn't get »Lohn«. The money that an employee gets is called »Gehalt«.

Also here: If you don't have a boss you are a freelancer, not an *Angestellter*. No boss = no *Gehalt*.

### Sold

There is a special group of working peoples: Soldiers (»Soldaten« in German). Soldiers don't get *Lohn* and they don't get a *Gehalt*. The money that a soldier gets for his or her service is called »Sold«.

Btw: The German word »Soldat« and the English word »Soldier« are both derived from the German name of the payment they get.

### Lehrlingsentschädigung

At least in Austria there is a fourth group of people who have a boss and who's payment has a special name:
A »Lehrling« (an apprentice) is a young person who is learning a job. I think this term is not officially used in Germany, I think they use »Auszubildender« instead, but I'm not absolutely sure about this.
The point is: A *Lehrling* in Austria doesn't get paid a *Lohn*, nor a *Gehalt*, not even a *Sold*. The money a *Lehrling* earns is called »Lehrlingsentschädigung« (literally: Apprenticeship compensation).

### Honorar

If you are a freelancer offering some service (»Dienstleistung«) or if you do occasional services (services only, not selling any goods), then you don't earn  every month the same amount of money. The money you earn depends on how many customers you have, and how many work you did for them. As a freelancer you don't get *Lohn*, *Gehalt*, *Sold* or *Lehrlingsentschädigung*. The money you get from your customers is called »Honorar«.

### Einkommen (for farmers)

A very special case are farmers. They are not workers, they are not employees, no soldiers, apprentices, not even freelancers (they don't offer services). They are non of them. So they do not get »Lohn«, »Gehalt« or any of the other payments described above. They are farmers, but their income has no special name. A farmers income is just called »Einkommen«. But as said before, this is also a generic term for any money that you get.

(to make it clear: If a freelancer or a farmer has employees, then those employees are »Arbeiter« or »Angestellte«, depending on the kind of work they have to do for their boss, and so they get »Lohn« or »Gehalt«. But the freelancer or farmer himself gets »Honorar« or just »Einkommen«.)

Comment: Du hast Recht. Während im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch der *Lehrling* für Handwerksberufe die Standardform ist *(Schreiner-, Metzger-* oder *Bäckerlehrling)* heißt es offiziell ausschließlich *Auszubildender.* Je größer die Firma, desto unwahrscheinlicher, dass man umgangssprachlich noch *Lehrling* sagt, also wäre man zum Beispiel »Azubi bei BMW« statt »Lehrling bei BMW«. Und für Lehrlinge gibt es auch eine spezielle Gehaltskategorie, deren Namen ich nicht kenne.

Comment: Und wie heißt das Einkommen von anderen Selbstständigen, die keine Dienstleister sind? Ist das vergleichbar mit dem Landwirt?

Comment: @Jan: Wenn ein Selbstständiger keine Dienstleistungen erbringt, muss er zwangsweise etwas verkaufen. Diese Waren stellt er entweder selbst aus irgendwelchen Rohmaterialien her (z.B. ein Geigenbauer), oder er verkauft Waren weiter, die er wo anders günstig eingekauft hat (das ist dann ein Händler). In beiden Fällen lebt diese Person also davon, Dinge zu verkaufen. Wie beim Landwirt gibt es dafür keine eigene Bezeichnung, also sagt man auch zu diesen Einkünften einfach nur »Einkommen«.

Comment: Danke für das Bestätigen meiner Vermutung =)

Comment: (Forts.:) Die Landwirte sind aber (zumindest in Ö) trotzdem etwas besonderes, weil »Einkünfte aus Land- und Forstwirtschaft« ganz anders besteuert werden als alle anderen Einkommensarten. Bei Landwirten wird viel pauschal (also ohne Belege) versteuert, wofür alle anderen Belege vorweisen müssen.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, in German, a manual labourer (Arbeiter) receives a "Lohn". A white-collar worker (Angestellter) or a civil servant (Beamter) receives a "Gehalt". "Entlohnung" covers both.

Comment: Actually for "Beamte", it's "Sold", not "Gehalt".

Answer (score 1):

A "Lohn" is a wage paid to a laborer for work by the hour or piece.

A "Gehalt" is an annual salary paid to an executive or professional.

An "Entlohnung" is a "discharge" of labor obligations (by the employ**er**), and can refer to either of the above payments.